# An almost continuous map from the $n$-dimensional ball to the unit circle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $S^1$ be the two dimensional unit circle. For two points $a,b \in S^1$, 
we denote $e(a,b)$ to be the absolute value of the smallest angle between $a$ and $b$ divided by $2\pi$. For example: $e(\exp(i\pi/4),(0,-1)) = 3\pi/4$. Note that $e$ is a metric on $S^1$.

Denoting the $n$ dimensional ball by $B^n$, 
**I am looking for a map** $T: B^n \rightarrow S^1$ that spreads the points of $B^n$ somewhat evenly on $S^1$, and that is continuous, except maybe for a few points (I would prefer as few as possible). I consider continuity with respect to the usual euclidean metric with $B^n$ and the metric $e$ with $S^1$.

A naive solution would be: Given a point $(a_1, a_2, ... , a_n)$ from $B^n$, add all the coordinates and perform modulo $1$ over the sum. This solution, however, does not seem to spread the points of $B^n$ evenly on $S^1$.

Another thing I tried is to perform [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) $n-2$ times, which leaves me with probably $n-2$ points of discontinuity.

I will appreciate any idea of a construction as described above, or pointers for something to read that will help me solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *evenly*?

Comment: Delete the origin from the ball, and map $x \to x/|x|$? You allow a point of discontinuity.

Comment: @PietroMajer: I don't know what is the right way to formulate the concept of *evenly*. I mean that T won't map most of the points to some small area of $S^1$. The image of a "randomly chosen" point from $B^n$ should be distributed evenly on $S^1$.

Comment: What about $f:B_n\to S^1$ defined as $$f(x):=\exp\Bigg( i\pi {\int_0^{x_1}(1-r^2)^{n-1\over2}dr\over \int_0^{1}(1-r^2)^{n-1\over2 }dr}\Bigg).$$
It verifies $f(\mathcal{L}^n )=\mathcal{H}^1 $ (that is $\mathcal{L}^n(f^{-1}(B))=\mathcal{H}^1(B)$ for any borel set $B\subset S^1$)

Comment: @BenMcKay: Thanks :) I can use your idea for $n=2$, but I really care about the cases where $n$ is much larger.

Comment: @PietroMajer: It might be too late at night on my side :) Did you use all the coordinates of the argument $x$? I didn't manage to follow what is happening there.

Comment: Should it be possible to perform stereographic projection directly from dimension $n$ to dimension $2$ ?

Comment: @real: just saying: project $B_n$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ of the $x_1$-axis, then stretch it and map it on $S^1$  so that any slice  $\{x\in B_n: a<x_1<b\}$ is mapped onto an arc  of $S^1$ of length proportional to the volume of the slice.

Comment: If we allow discontinuity on measure 0 set, then consider $D^n=CS^{n-1},\ S^{n-1}=S^1\ast S^{n-3}$.